Dropdown selection with Powershell and Selenium doesn´t work reliable
I`m using Powershell and Selenium to automate a browser to fetch some data from CBOE website. To get the full option chain I have to make selections first from two dropdown menus. The first dropdown menu (options range) always works fine but the second one (expirations) is making problems. In 50% of the attempts it shifts back to the previous setting after I have chosen "All" as selection.
Doesn´t matter how many "Start - Sleep" commands I put into the code, it doesn´t change anything.
$browser = Create-Browser -browser Edge
$browser.Url = https://www.cboe.com/delayed_quotes/tsla/quote_table   # TSLA just as an example
$navi = $browser.Navigate() 

Start-Sleep -Seconds 1

$browser.Manage().Window.FullScreen()

#Confirm Cookie-Message (Agree Button)

$agreeButton = $browser.FindElement([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::XPath("//button[contains(@class, 'button--solid') and contains(@class, 'privacy-alert__agree-button') and text()='I agree']"))
$agreeButton.Click()

#Set Optionsrange Menu to "All" 

$optionsrange = $browser.FindElement([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::XPath("//input[contains(@class, 'ReactSelect__input') and contains(@id, 'select_5')]"))

$actions = [OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions]::new($browser)
$actions.SendKeys($optionsrange,'All')
$actions.SendKeys($optionsrange,[OpenQA.Selenium.Keys]::Enter)
$actions.Build()
$actions.Perform()

Start-Sleep -Seconds 3

#Set Expirations Menu to "All"  ### This is where the problems occure ###

$expirations = $browser.FindElement([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::XPath("//input[contains(@class, 'ReactSelect__input') and contains(@id, 'select_7')]"))

$actions = [OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions]::new($browser)
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
$actions.SendKeys($expirations,'All')
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
$actions.SendKeys($expirations,[OpenQA.Selenium.Keys]::Enter)
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
$actions.Build()
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
$actions.Perform()

Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

# Click "View Option Chain" button 

$viewchainbutton = $browser.FindElement([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::XPath("//button[contains(@class, 'Button__StyledButton-cui__sc-1ahwe65-2') and contains(@class, 'hMfKkd')]"))
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
$viewchainbutton.Click()

# Click Link Button to start the download

$browser.FindElement([OpenQA.Selenium.By]::XPath("//a[contains(@type, 'button') and contains(@download, 'quotedata.csv')]")).click()

Start-Sleep -Seconds 2

Write-Output "Ready"

$browser.Quit()

Has anyone an idea why the first dropdown works perfectly while the other one is making problems?
Kind regards
Marc
